# Can I create Multiple Client ID in Google console?

Tags: android, google-client, google-client-login, appauth

**I have one query regarding usage of client Id in Google Developers console.**

For one project, someone had created one clientId for using Google fit API's for storing fitness data. And I don't have the credentials for account used for creating the Client-id. Also I'm not able to find the client-id anywhere in code.

Now I want to add Google Sign-in using "AppAuth for Android". For which I need to add `clientId and redirectUri` in code.

**My question is, can I create new `clientId and redirectUri` with any other account using same SHA1 fingerprint and package name? or Do I have to use the same existing client-id? (which doesn't seem to be a possible way)**

**Edit1:**

As @iainmcgin mentioned I tried to create one using the same SHA-1 and package name, but getting below error.

`The fingerprint that you specified is already being used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project.`

Comment: yes you can create, is it mandatory to use same sha ? if not you can go with new sha

Comment: @JanardhanR Yes, it is mandatory to use same SHA-1 key and package name too

Comment: is app already published on playstore?

Comment: @JanardhanR Yes, it's already published. That's why I don't want to change keystore, package and SHA-1

Comment: what is happening if you try to create new Android OAuth2 client ID?

Comment: @JanardhanR It's not allowing to create. Giving error `The fingerprint that you specified is already being used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project.`

Answer (score 1):

Google engineer on the Google Identity Platform team here - we enforce a 1:1 mapping between client IDs and package name + certificate hash, so you can't create another client ID. You'll need to regain access to the project that defined the original client ID; if you are not able to do that, contact me at iainmcgin@google.com with the details of your app and I'll try and put you in touch with people that can verify your ownership of the app and either delete the original client, or give you access to the original project, whichever turns out to be more appropriate.